# AngularJS: On Change of Parent DropDown Option Also Changes the Dependant Drop Down Options Associated with Other Parents

Tags: angularjs, multipleselection

Visit this Link to view the problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CPxvE4SC6ScTH57s6CmQ?p=preview

index.html*************************

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <table>
                <thead>
                <th>Plan</th>
                <th>Options</th>
                </thead>    
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="order_detail in order_details">
                        <td>
                            <select id="plan_id" name="plan_id" ng-model="order_detail.plan_id" ng-options="plan.plan_id as plan.name for plan in plans" required ng-change="loadPlanTemplates()">
                                <option value="">-- choose plan --</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="plan_option_id" name="plan_option_id" ng-model="order_detail.plan_option_id" ng-options="plan_option.plan_option_id as plan_option.name for plan_option in plan_options" required ng-change="loadPlanTemplateValues()" >
                                <option value="">-- choose option --</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

script.js******************************

```
 var moduleMyAPP = angular.module('myApp', []);
            moduleMyAPP.controller('myController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http) {

            $scope.order_details = [{plan_id: null, plan_option_id: null}, {plan_id: null, plan_option_id: null}, {plan_id: null, plan_option_id: null}];
            $scope.plans = [{plan_id: 1, name: 'Gold'}, {plan_id: 2, name: 'Platinium'}, {plan_id: 3, name: 'Silver'}];
            $scope.loadPlanTemplates = function () {
                var planId = this.order_detail.plan_id;

                switch (planId) {
                    case 1:
                        $scope.plan_options = [
                            {plan_option_id: 1, name: '10 Years'},
                            {plan_option_id: 2, name: '20 Years'},
                            {plan_option_id: 3, name: '30 Years'},
                        ];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $scope.plan_options = [
                            {plan_option_id: 1, name: '5 Years'},
                            {plan_option_id: 2, name: '7 Years'},
                            {plan_option_id: 3, name: '9 Years'},
                        ];
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $scope.plan_options = [
                            {plan_option_id: 1, name: '2 Years'},
                            {plan_option_id: 2, name: '3 Years'},
                            {plan_option_id: 3, name: '4 Years'},
                        ];
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your code.

1. You gave the same ID to each select, I changed it to be `id="plan_id{{$index}}"` so you could differentiate.
2. You used the same object for all 3 `ng-model` of the options dropdown. I changed it to be a 2 dimensional array, and just update the relevant one. I also changed the function to use the `$index` from the `ng-repeat` so the function will know what needs to be changed:

`ng-change="loadPlanTemplates({{$index}})`

and

`$scope.loadPlanTemplates = function (index) { ... }`

The array is initialized at the beginning:

`$scope.plan_options = [[],[],[]];`

And then in each case you have:

```
$scope.plan_options[index] = [
              {plan_option_id: 1, name: '10 Years'},
              {plan_option_id: 2, name: '20 Years'},
              {plan_option_id: 3, name: '30 Years'},
               ];
              break;
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uI2rsRfQRHRCIVktKtJm?p=preview)